# Creating texture from a sample in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

I am working in photoshop, and I am trying to create a texture to use as a background image.

[image]

Ideally, I could make the text on this page disappear and be left with a blank page.

My attempt so far (again be nice haha, I'm more into the code-side of things than design):
[image]
You can see that I've taken a small sample (from the text around house of lords scotch) and duplicated it 1000 times.  What's the best way to blend the image together?  Or if there is a better way in general, I'd appreciate hearing it!

Thanks.

Comment: I think your best bet is to recreate it. Either from a scratch or by using similar texture(s). The sample texture is too small. I mean you could try to struggle with it and use every possible area, but even so, you'd still probably have to blend in some other texture to make it work. At that point the original texture would be nothing but the base color.

Comment: What size were you looking for? That's an interior page of a [playbill for "Cat on a Hot Tin Roof"](http://theater-words.com/tag/playbill/), and it'll be enormously easier to work with the cover. Removing the print from the page you're using (which has had one of the ads replaced) is easy (tedious, but easy); putting the wove paper texture back is another matter entirely, and there isn't enough source texture to work from on that page (or any of the other interior pages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the color picker tool to make a custom gradient, add some noise and some minor vignette. I can make an example for you if you link the reference.

[EDIT]

Created an example to show you the outcome of the steps above.
[image: Used texture and source image to add detail]

Comment: I'd appreciate that, the texture I got from this: https://www.google.com/search?q=old+playbill&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=XTwHVOLxJ4SVgwTXkoCACA&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1680&bih=952#q=old+playbill+ad&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:svga&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=vZWBNcEjiGR05M%253A%3BAvZAeWsvmSCxgM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftheaterwords.files.wordpress.com%252F2013%252F02%252Fscan-130330002.jpg%253Fw%253D660%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Ftheater-words.com%252Fpage%252F3%252F%3B660%3B883

Comment: How did you get darkened borders? I made another one as well, it's not as good.  And you have some scratches in there (in a good way)... how did you achieve those?

Comment: @Peege151 No Probs, I just blended the pattern I made over the top of the original page. Added some random paper tear to it with overlays and such :)

Comment: What tool did you use to blend?  I was trying to figure out how to do that.  Or did you go up to the menus (file / layer etc(sorry for noobness))?

Comment: @Peege151 Sorry for the late reply, you can use the likes of content aware, and the clone stamp tool to get a good look. Then you will have to layer on some scratches etc, lastly try the burn tool around the edges for some shadows

Comment: No worries, I appreciate the help.